# Python Unicode object and C API ( retrieving char* from pyunicode objects )

Tags: python, string, unicode, binding, ascii

I am currently binding all of my C++ engine classes to python for game play scripting purposes.
The latest challenge is that when say you make a variable in the script a string such as

```
string = 'hello world'
```

this becomes a PyUnicodeObject. Next we want to call a function on this object in the script from a bound C side function. PrintToLog( string ), as an example lets say this c-function is as such

```
void PrintToLog( const char * thisString )
{
   //file IO stuff as expected
   myLog << thisString;
   //more stuff involving fileIO
}
```

So my binding needs to extract a char * from the PyUnicodeObject which will be passed at first by the python to my generic function handler, which in turn will extract and covert the pyobjects to the proper c-side type and pass it to my function.

The only function I can find extracts a wchar_t*... Is there anyway to get the ascii representation since we will only be using the ascii character set.

EDIT: I am using Python 3.2 where all strings are unicode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the function you're looking for is [PyUnicode_AsASCIIString](http://docs.python.org/c-api/unicode.html#ascii-codecs). This will give you a non-unicode (ASCII) python string. And then you can take the normal approach for extracting a `char*` from that.

Comment: Is the object returned still defined as a PyUnicodeObject though? If so I could then call PyUnicode_AS_DATA to get the objects internal buffer, but if this is not returned as such what function exists that will allow me to extract the char *?

Comment: Ok, that seems to get results. At the moment it is a string of random data, but I was able to extract data. Once I find what I am doing wrong everything should work out fine. Thank you for the help you two =)

Comment: (if you're still around...) Could you please expand on "the normal approach for extracting a `char*` from that"?  I'm trying to figure out how to get a `char*`, and I see that PyUnicode_AsASCIIString returns a `PyObject*`... could I perhaps use `PyUnicode_AsUTF8`?

Comment: @lindes Sure, I wrote some (hopefully close-to-valid) pseudo-code here: https://gist.github.com/eberle1080/7103201

Answer (score 12):

I was facing a similar problem with Python3. I solved it as follows.

If you have a [PyUnicodeObject](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/unicode.html) "mystring", do something like

```
PyObject * ascii_mystring=PyUnicode_AsASCIIString(mystring);
PrintToLog(PyBytes_AsString(ascii_mystring));
Py_DECREF(ascii_mystring);
```

PyBytes is explained [here](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html).

Comment: Would also be good to add a `NULL` check after `PyUnicode_AsASCIIString` in case string cannot be ASCII encoded.