# How Does String Conversion Between PyUnicode String and C String Work?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api, python-internals

I have a PyUnicode object I'm trying to convert back to a C string (char *).

The way I am trying to do it does not seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
PyObject * objectCompName = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(compTuple, (Py_ssize_t) 0);
PyObject * ooCompName = PyUnicode_AsASCIIString(objectCompName);
char * compName = PyBytes_AsString(ooCompName);
Py_DECREF(ooCompName);
```

Is there another/better way I should be doing this?

Comment: Define "does not seem to be working".  Do you get crashes?  Results different from what you wanted?  In either case, exactly what?

Comment: With which version of Python are you working?

Comment: @JohnBollinger it segfaults when it gets here. Python 3.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote on both my question and the answer?

Comment: You do not check the return values of your API calls, nor test whether an exception has been raised.  That would be a good place to start.

Comment: NMDV, but the question *is* rather lacking in detail and reproducibility.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Not neccisarly asking for my code to be debugged here. I gave an example of what I have tried, and am asking for a solution to convert a PyUnicode String to a Char * in C as mine is not working.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783493/python-unicode-object-and-c-api-retrieving-char-from-pyunicode-objects/16905726

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If UTF-8 encoded `char *` is OK, you should definitely use [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize) (which requires Python 3.3):

```
PyObject * objectCompName = PySequence_GetItem(compTuple, 0);
if (! objectCompName) {
    return NULL;
}

Py_ssize_t size;
char *ptr = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(objectCompName, &size);
if (!ptr) {
    return NULL;
}

// notice that the string pointed to by ptr is not guaranteed to stay forever,
// and you need to copy it, perhaps by `strdup`.
```

Also, do understand that is **mandatory** to check the return value of each and every `Py*` function call that you ever execute in your code.

Here the `PyTuple_GetItem` will return `NULL` if `compTuple` is not a `tuple`, or `0` causes `IndexError`. `PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize` will return `NULL` if `objectCompName` is not a `str` object. Ignore the return value and CPython crashes with `SIGSEGV` when the conditions are right.

Comment: The PyUnicode string is originally made in another C function using `PyUnicode_DecodeASCII`.

Comment: In that case `PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize` is very fine.

Comment: Okay great. You state that it is "mandatory" to check the return values. I do plan to check them, I just haven't been as I wanted to just test and make sure it works first. Is it actually a requirement to check the return value, or you are just saying that is a very good practice?

Comment: **Yes, it is absolutely mandatory, not only a good practice.**

Comment: Is there a reason for this? I have added these checks and implemented your suggestion and it does work.

Comment: [Because documentation says so](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#intermezzo-errors-and-exceptions)

Comment: Haha now with the check on the `objectCompName` there is an exception thrown by Python: `SystemError: ../Objects/tupleobject.c:139: bad argument to internal function`

Comment: So your tuple wasn't a tuple?

Comment: Correct, so it is definitely a good thing that you told me that I need these checks as now I see what was causing underlying issues. Thanks.

Comment: @Fogest that SystemError does not look nice. Perhaps use `PySequence_GetItem` instead, it allows `list` too; gives `TypeError` if it is not a sequence

Comment: The problem does appear to be because it was a list instead of a tuple. I swapped it to a PyList instead, but I will change it to PySequence as that ones looks even safer. And that fixes that issue, but now it is dying later at the check for `!ptr` after the `PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize` call: `TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
`. You mentioned the `TypeError`, but it is throwing this typeerror at the conversion stage not at the PySequence area checks.

Comment: I just did a `PyUnicode_Check` on the objectCompName and it is not returning true. However I also have some integers that are grabbed using the same `PySequence_GetItem()` method and they are returning true on the `PyLong_Check`, so there is something going on with these strings.

Comment: And I think I know why. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks for all the help. You solved my issue and helped me put in better error checking!

Answer (score 2):

You need to first convert your python PyUnicode to a non-unicode python string (read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/unicode.html#ascii-codecs) , then you can easily convert the result into `char*` .

Below is a pseudo code to help you proceed:

```
// Assumption: you have a variable named "pyobj" which is
// a pointer to an instance of PyUnicodeObject.

PyObject* temp = PyUnicode_AsASCIIString(pyobj);
if (NULL == temp) {
    // Means the string can't be converted to ASCII, the codec failed
    printf("Oh noes\n");
    return;
}

// Get the actual bytes as a C string
char* c_str = PyByteArray_AsString(temp);

// Use the string in some manner
printf("The python unicode string is: %s\n", c_str);

// Make sure the temp stuff gets cleaned up at the end
Py_XDECREF(temp);
```

Comment: The line with the `PyByteArray_AsString(temp);` is segfaulting.

Comment: Use `PyBytes_AsString(temp)`.