# Embedding Python in C: Error in linking - undefined reference to PyString_AsString

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-internals, python-embedding

I am trying to embed a python program inside a C program. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04

I try to embed python 2.7 and python 3.4 interpreter in the same C code base (as separate applications). The compilation and linking works when embedding python 2.7 but not for the python 3.4. It fails during the linker stage.

Here is my C code (just an example not real code)

**simple.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc, *pValue;
    char module[] = "get_version";
    char func[] = "get_version";
    char module_path[] = ".";

    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *sys_path = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyList_Append(sys_path, PyUnicode_FromString(module_path));

    pName = PyUnicode_FromString(module);
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if(pModule != NULL)
    {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, func);
        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
        {
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Python version: %s\n", PyString_AsString(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**get_version.py**

```
import sys

def get_version():
    version = '.'.join(str(v) for v in sys.version_info[:3])
    print("version: ", version)
    return version
```

I compile the program using gcc. First with compiling and linking flags set to python 2.7 I run the compilation and linking by using following command:

```
gcc `python-config --cflags` simple.c `python-config --ldflags`
```

The flags expand as:

***python-config --cflags:*** `-I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7  -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes`

***python-config --ldflags:*** `-L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions`

It works fine without any issues. When I try to compile the same with python3.4 flags it fails:

```
gcc `python3-config --cflags` simple.c `python3-config --ldflags`
```

The flags expand as:

***python-config --cflags:*** `-I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/python3.4m  -Wno-unused-result -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes`

***python-config --ldflags:*** `-L/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.4m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions`

**Error message:**

```
simple.c: In function ‘main’:
simple.c:27:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyString_AsString’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                 printf("Python version: %s\n", PyString_AsString(pValue));
                 ^
simple.c:27:17: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
/tmp/ccaoMdTo.o: In function `main':
/home/vagrant/c_python_api/simple.c:27: undefined reference to `PyString_AsString'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried by changing the order in which linker objects are specified. But no luck. Any idea why this would be the case?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Python 3 does not have `PyString_AsString` any more](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/cporting.html#str-unicode-unification); the Python 3 `str` correspond to Python 2 `unicode` objects; the names of the functions for handling `str` in Python 3 are `PyUnicode_`-prefixed in the C-API.

Thus this line:

```
printf("Python version: %s\n", PyString_AsString(pValue));
```

could be changed to use [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8) on Python 3:

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
printf("Python version: %s\n", PyUnicode_AsUTF8(pValue));
#else
printf("Python version: %s\n", PyString_AsString(pValue));
#endif
```

---

(Not that passing `NULL` to `printf` `%s` will have undefined behaviour, so you'd want to check that a non-NULL pointer was returned)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. The solution provided by you worked. I knew that Python3 strings are unicode encoded by default, should have given a thought about it. However as said in your solution UTF8String  are PyObject and cannot be converted into native char. As described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16905726/4104863) the should be additional function call to PyBytes_AsString(). I will edit the answer to include this.

Comment: Ah sorry :D I was writing the answer in haste: fixed

Comment: @JahanBalasubramaniam should have been `PyUnicode_AsUTF8`; this returns a shared pointer to the string encoded as UTF-8, which is valid for as long as the `str` itself exists.

Comment: `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` exists in Python 3.3 forward; it is easiest to not support Python 3.2 at all, since so many changes went to the C-API of `str` in Python 3.