# Error using "PyUnicode_AsUTF8"

Tags: cython

I am trying to write a function in Cython to processs a lits of strings. In the code below, I am trying to convert a list of unicode `str` objects (in Python 3) to a table of `char*`, which then is used in order to search for substrings.

I found a solution for Python 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511309/fast-string-array-cython) but this solution is dependent to object `PyString_AsString` which is available only in Python 2, whereas in Python 3 we are supposed to use `PyUnicode_AsUTF8`, which I found out about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530637/embedding-python-in-c-error-in-linking-undefined-reference-to-pystring-asstri). When I tried to use `PyUnicode_AsUTF8`, I run into this error:

> :31:16: 'PyUnicode_AsUTF8' is not a constant, variable or function identifier

I am pretty much out of ideas. Whatever I try causes some sort of error.

The code

```
import cython
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc, PyMem_Realloc, PyMem_Free
from cpython.string cimport PyUnicode_AsUTF8
from libc.string cimport strstr

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def start(itsstr, tokens):
    cdef size_t s
    cdef size_t t
    cdef size_t ns = len(itsstr)
    cdef size_t nt = len(tokens)
    cdef const char** t_str = _char_table(itsstr, ns)
    cdef const char** t_tok = _char_table(tokens, nt)
    cdef unicode x
    for s in xrange(ns):
        for t in xrange(nt):
            if strstr(t_str[s], t_tok[t]):
                x = itsstr[s]
    PyMem_Free(t_str)
    PyMem_Free(t_tok)

cdef const char** _char_table(s, const size_t n):
    cdef char** t = <char**>PyMem_Malloc(n * sizeof(char*))
    cdef size_t i = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
        temp = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(s[i])
        t[i] = temp
    return t
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a CPython's C-API function which doesn't exist in Cython's cpython-headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594979/how-to-call-a-cpythons-c-api-function-which-doesnt-exist-in-cythons-cpython-h)

Answer (score 4):

Cython doesn't wrap the function `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` in [cpython.string](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/cpython/string.pxd). So you have to do it yourself:

```
#instead of from cpython.string cimport PyUnicode_AsUTF8
cdef extern from "Python.h":
    const char* PyUnicode_AsUTF8(object unicode) except NULL
```

Actually, in versions prior to Python 3.7 it was [`char * PyUnicode_AsUTF8(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8), but having const in front of it doesn't disturb Cython also for older versions.

`except NULL` is important so cython will automatically handle possible errors (thanks @socketpair).

---

In more recent versions a very similar function `PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize` is already wrapped and could be used.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to start with this but I'll try to find something!

Comment: @Celdor: You just have to replace the `cimport`  with the code from the answer, there is noting more to it...

Comment: I see, I thought I'd have to implement it by myself. Thanks :) I am going to test it as soon as I can

Comment: Extremely important: add `except NULL` in order fro Cython to check NULL value and raise exception automatically! so `const char* PyUnicode_AsUTF8(object x) except NULL`

Comment: @socketpair this is probably a good idea, however Cython itself wraps the similar `PyUnicodeAsUTF8AndSize` without except, see https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/cpython/unicode.pxd#L397C17-L397C40

Comment: @ead The missing `except` in Cython is a mistake I think. I'll fix it shortly.