# How to call a C-API function such as PyUnicode_READ_CHAR from Cython?

Tags: python, cython, cpython

I'm using Cython to speed up a function that operates over a string (unicode, CPython 3.6).

How do I call CPython's `Py_UCS4 val = PyUnicode_READ_CHAR(my_string, my_index)` from my Cython `.pyx` code? I cannot figure out the correct way to import and use the C-API from Cython.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cython doesn't wrap the whole CPython's C-API in `cpython.*`-headers, only the most important part. If a function is not wrapped, it can be always done on the fly, e.g.:

```
#instead of from cpython.unicode cimport PyUnicode_READ_CHAR
cdef extern from *:
    Py_UCS4 PyUnicode_READ_CHAR(object o, Py_ssize_t index)
```

After that the function can be used in Cython.

Comment: Thanks! I rolled back your edit of my question because it completely changed the question meaning, but your answer here is great.

Comment: @user124114 Fair enough. I've changed your question, because I wanted to use it as dupe target for similar issues. `PyUnicode_READ_CHAR` alone is not very useful for others, but could be an example for a function from C-API which isn't wrapped in Cython headers -> this has a potential to be useful for many people. SO is a collection of high quality Q&A which can be reused, thus changing/improving questions and making them more useful is as important as correct answers.

Comment: I see. I edited – hopefully a compromise? I personally always google with concrete words, so an abstracted title wouldn't help me. Especially when I don't even know the right terminology yet ("Cython's cpython-headers").